# HATEOAS and Search API (FIQL / RQL)

Tags: java, spring, search, restful-architecture, spring-hateoas

I already post this question on Spring Forum, but somebody told me to move the question here, i think it's a good option.

I would like to know how can i implement FIQL or RQL for make a Search API in FullREST / HateOAS.

I Googled for this and didn't see anything, just the implementation of CXF.

I know that we can maybe make something with Matrix Variable ? But i'm looking for something more "friendly", like the CXF Implementation, or in the "Spring Way"

Thanks for your help

Comment: show us some of your own ideas in code, and we can help you improve it

Comment: Hi, badly the work in this part is deleted, it was a POC. We made complicated code for nothing good, this is why i posted the question ^^ Just to see if somebody think about FIQL like HATEOAS was done in Spring ;)